# selecting limited rows from child table in one query

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Sorry, may be a stupid question. 
I have 2 tables with parent - child relationship. For each parent, there are more than 10 records in the child table. I want to get only 3 records from child table for each parent. Is it possible with one query in mysql ?

Comment: Follow the link (above) on the `[greatest-n-per-group]` tag. Or the links under the **Related** header, on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)´s a link to an article that explains how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. SELECT users.id, user_name, comment_text
FROM user_comments
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = user_comments.user_id
WHERE user_comments.id
IN (

SELECT user_comments2.id
FROM user_comments user_comments2
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_comments user_comments3 ON ( user_comments2.user_id = user_comments3.user_id
AND user_comments2.id < user_comments3.id ) 
GROUP BY user_comments2.id
HAVING COUNT( * ) < 4
)
ORDER BY user_id, id DESC  works for me

Answer (score 0):

in SQL for selecting only specific number of records from the table we use `top` key word

`select top 3 from employee`

will return only top 3 records even if the table consists of more than 3 records.

for my SQL you can write the query in

`SELECT * FROM [tablename] LIMIT 0,10;`

Note if you select both parent-child data in single query you will repeat parent details with respect to your child table.

Comment: `TOP` is SQL-Server specific. MySQL has `LIMIT`.